# What is the relation between the $\min\{a+d , b+c \}-b-d$ and $\min\{a-b , c-d \}$?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, elementary-set-theory

For any $a,b,c$ and $d$ in $\mathbb{R^+}$. What is the relation between the

$\min\{a+d , b+c \}-b-d$

and

$\min\{a-b , c-d \}$ ? How to prove that relation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is useful to prove that $\min\{x+t,y+t\}=\min\{x,y\}+t$, which easily follows from $x < y \Leftrightarrow x + t < y + t$.

Now apply this result for $x=a+d$, $y=b+c$, $t=-b-d$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:
For any $a,b,c \in \mathbb{R}$, you have $\min\{a,b\} + c = \min\{a+c, b+c\}$.

Answer (score 0):

$\min\{a+d,b+c\}-b-d = \min\{a+d-(b+d),b+c-(b+d)\} = \min\{a-b,c-d\}$